# busybox ip link show doesn't work

Tags: busybox

I can't see the MAC address of my phone when I use command `busybox ip link show` on my rooted LG phone. Here is screen shot:

[image]

Does anyone know what seems to be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just `busybox ip link`. Also, `netcfg` is capable of showing your MAC address.

Comment: busybox ip link do the same thing, but netcfg showed MAC adress. thanks :D